# If $Y$ is a sub-Gaussian random variable, must $Y-E(Y\mid X)$ be also sub-Gaussian?

Tags: probability, statistics

> **Question.** If $Y$ is a sub-Gaussian random variable, must the regression residual $\varepsilon=Y-E(Y\mid X)$ be also sub-Gaussian?

In terms of the variance, it is well known that $\mathrm{var}(\varepsilon)\leq \mathrm{var}(Y)$. However, I can't find out a way to prove (or disprove) the sub-Gaussianity of $\varepsilon$ when $Y$ is sub-Gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the following: a random variable $Z$ is sub-Gaussian if and only if $\sup_{p\geqslant 1}\lVert Z\rVert_p/\sqrt p<\infty$.

Since the conditional expectation is a contraction in $\mathbb L^p$-spaces, that is, $\left\lVert\mathbb E\left[Z\mid\mathcal A\right]\right\rVert_p\leqslant \lVert Z\rVert_p$, we have
$$
\left\lVert \varepsilon\right\rVert_p/\sqrt p\leqslant 2\left\lVert Y\right\rVert_p/\sqrt p
$$
which gives finiteness of $\sup_{p\geqslant 1}\left\lVert \varepsilon\right\rVert_p/\sqrt p$.